# magento cart api rest/V1/carts/mine/totals/

Tags: magento2

when I hit this API I am getting this error

```
 "message": "\"%fieldName\" is required. Enter and try again.",
    "parameters": {
        "fieldName": "cartId"
    },
```

I pass cartId in the body

```
{
    "cartId":"1"

}
```

Comment: Which API you called ?

Comment: https://vouchereek2.test/rest/V1/carts/4/totals

Answer (score 0):

Just Pass the Customer Token in Authorization's Bearer Token in your cart API.

**- Get Cart Totals**

- Method : GET
- Endpoint: `{{base_url}}/rest/default/V1/carts/mine/totals`
- Your Headers should be - Authorization Bearer "yourcustomeraccesstoken"
  [image: cart total]

**- How to generate Customer Token:**

1.First of all, **Set End Point** of REST API :

```
{{base_url}}/rest/default/V1/integration/customer/token
```

2.then  set **Method : POST**

3.In the request body, include the following parameters:

- username: The customer's email address
- password: The customer's password

Example Request Body:

```
{
  "username": "customer_email@example.com",
  "password": "customer_password"
}
```

[image: customer token]